# Access computers from a VPN in an embedded network

Tags: networking, vpn

I have two routers. One is a main router that is connected to the internet, one is being used as a VPN connection. I don't want all my computers to be on the VPN, just some media computers. The setup is working great, but the problem is my computers on the VPN network can't access the computers on the main network. Is there any way I can make that happen? I know if I disable the VPN and just leave the router as a DHCP I can access the network resources without any problems. Here's a diagram of the setup:

[image]

I - Internet
A - Main router and connection to internet 
B - VPN router 
C1 & C2 - computers on main network 
C3 & C4 - computers on VPN network

In a nutshell I want C3 to be able to access C1 without having to move it between networks. I was thinking of using a computer as a bridge and connect it to both networks, but I rather not go out and get a computer just for that. Another alternative I was thinking about is to connect C1 to the VPN, but wouldn't that mean that when I transfer from C1 to C3 it has to go through the internet and come back into the network?

Sorry about the poor & confusing explanation.

### UPDATE

Just as more information, C3 and C4 are media centers, android devices and NAS enclosures. C1 and c2 are computers but they are too far away from my routers for me to pop in an extra NIC and link the two networks together. Also I am looking for a solution where I don't have to leave a computer on 24/7.

Comment: What type of VPN are you using?

Comment: I'm using l2tp vpn

Comment: What sort of access are you looking for? Is it http, ftp, windows file sharing?

Comment: I am looking to access windows file shares or SMB shares.